# Cream or butter in a pudding

Tags: butter, cream, pudding

I wish to know what would be the difference between using cream or butter in a pudding.

I have never used cream instead of butter and do not even know if maybe both can be used at the same time?

Comment: What, exactly, do *you* mean by "pudding"?

Comment: Is this in relation to [this](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59972/vanilla-pudding-could-someone-explain-this-recipe-to-me) question? Considering your question history, I'm going to assume that you mean "pudding" as defined in the tag.

Comment: @Catija, what other type of pudding is there? To me "pudding" has such a singular, defined meaning as "pebble". :) I am sort of creeped out you would go snooping through my question history, though.

Comment: Actually, in non-US English speaking countries, "pudding" is a generic term for "dessert"... so it can mean a wide variety of things. And I didn't go "snooping through your question history"... I remembered your previous question and assumed it was connected. I'm here a lot.

Comment: @Catija, well where I'm from "pudding" means only one thing - the [creamy-like dessert](http://www.eatbydate.com/wp-content/uploads/pudding-ck-522543-l.jpeg). It has never been associated with anything else and I haven't seen it being associated with anything else in movies/tv from other countries so I did not know. Sorry about implicating you, lately I have learned a lot of internet people snoop around other people's profiles and such, so...

Answer (score 1):

Butter helps to set whatever you're incorporating it into more firmly. It's also delicious.

Cream is liquid and will remain liquid, unless whipped and incorporated.

Honestly, it all depends on what you're making. Sometimes they can be interchangeable and sometimes they definitely cannot.